# Using $(function () Versus using $(document).ready(function () {

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

i have implemented a java script to bounce an image on my asp.net mvc 3 web application, if i write the Jscript as follow it will work fine:-

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#to-get-bigger").mouseover(function () {
                $(this).effect("bounce);
            });
        });
```

**but if i write it this way it will not work !! ,, so what might be the reason behind this :-**

```
$(function () {
    $("to-get-bigger").mouseover(function () {
        $(this).effect("bounce");
    });
});
```

Comment: Are you using notepad ?!? Switch to something with code coloring, it will make finding typos easier. Like [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/)

Comment: Or [Sublime Text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com/2) :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are missing the hash # for your selector. I've fixed it:

```
$(function () {
    $("#to-get-bigger").mouseover(function () {
        $(this).effect("bounce");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You forgot the `#` in front of `"to-get-bigger"`.

It's a typo.